# Зависает внешний жесткий диск при загрузке с торрента

Tags: железо, hdd, диск

Зависает внешний диск, если на него скачивать большой файл торрентом, > 2 gb, скачивается 10 - 100 мегабайт и зависает программа и сам диск, торрент не закрывается и диск не получается отключить, мигает лампочка на диске. Если скачать на внутренний диск, а потом скопировать, то работает нормально. Проверял на разных компьютерах и операционных системах, везде проблема та же

Comment: А если торрент клиент закрыть то диск оживает? Просто есть предположение, что диск лочится самой программой, а моргания это всего лишь индикация обмены данными.

Comment: торрент не закрывается, а даже если закрывается, то ничего не меняется